# SAPUI5 Cordova iOS app Ajax calls not working (hang infinitely)

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, sapui5

I'm currently building a SAPUI5 Cordova app for iOS. I'm using Cordova 8, iOS 11.0.3 and xcode 9.2 The problem is that none of my Ajax calls seem to be working (they hang indefinitely without even returning an error code). This seems to be a common problem, as there are quite a few threads surrounding this issue already, but none of the proposed solutions in those threads seem to work in my app.
So far, I've tried the following things:

Setting CSP in the meta tag of index.html:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' *; media-src * 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'" />
```

Setting the App Transport Security settings in the info.plist file of the xcode project:

[image]

Importing the cordova-whitelist-plugin and setting access origin, allow-intent and allow-navigation to *:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="opensap.myapp.eventapp" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>eventapp2</name>
<description />
<author email="dev@sap.com" href="http://www.sap.com">SAP Product and Innovation</author>
<content src="webapp/index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="^2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="^2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="^3.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^3.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.1.0" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" requires-certificate-transparency="false" requires-forward-secrecy="false" />
<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icon/icon_android_36.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icon/icon_android_48.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icon/icon_android_72.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icon/icon_android_96.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <icon height="57" src="res/icon/icon_ios_57.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="72" src="res/icon/icon_ios_72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="114" src="res/icon/icon_ios_114.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="144" src="res/icon/icon_ios_144.png" width="144" />
    <splash height="480" src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    <splash height="960" src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="2048" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="768" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="1536" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1136" src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1142" />
</platform>
<platform name="windows" />
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="ShowTitle" value="false" />
    <preference name="LogLevel" value="VERBOSE" />
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeout" value="80000" />
    <preference name="UrlScheme" value="" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
</platform>
<preference name="sap-development-version" value="0.0.1" />
<preference name="hybridapprevision" value="1" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
<icon src="res/icon/icon_512.png" />
<plugin name="com.unarin.cordova.beacon" spec="https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
<engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
<engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.4" />
```

Any tips or suggestions on how to get this to work?

EDIT: tried setting an exception on domain level, but this doesn't work either:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add called domain to your **info.plist** in Exception domain section and disable CertificateTransparency, and set TLS1.0.

```
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>yourdomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.0</string>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried your suggestion but I'm still not getting any response when calling the webservice. I updated my initial post with a new screenshot of my current info.plist settings.

Comment: Hmm and if you call webservice from outside the app (from a webbrowser) it respond correctly?

Comment: That's right, on Android the ajax calls work perfectly fine. However, I noticed that there's also an info.plist file in my CordovaLib.xcodeproj/Cordova folder (up until now, I made changes in eventsapp2-Info.plist located in the Resources/config folder). That info.plist file is listed in red and I don't seem to be able to make changes to that file.

Comment: Hmm you can try with cache bug but i have notice it is solved.. take a look here [https://www.mgcwebsites.co.uk/solved-jquery-ajax-request-not-working-iphones/](https://www.mgcwebsites.co.uk/solved-jquery-ajax-request-not-working-iphones/)  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

Comment: Yeah, I tried both setting cache to false in $.ajaxSetup and in the header of my Ajax call, but it still doesn't work.